# Having issues with file path handling after converting my application to an .exe

Tags: python, logging, pyinstaller, filepath

I'm trying to run python file by from a different directory after converting it into an exe.

For example let's say below is my project structure:

```
project_name/core/main.py
project_name/core/app1.py
project_name/core/app2.py
project_name/logs/migration.log
project_name/config/userconfig/user.json
project_name/config/systemconfig/system.json
project_name/logging.ini
```

And my `logging.ini` file contains:

```
[loggers]
keys=root,main,app1,app2

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler,fileHandler

[formatters]
keys=simpleFormatter,json

[logger_root]
level=CRITICAL
handlers=consoleHandler

[logger_main]
level=DEBUG
handlers=fileHandler
qualname=main

[logger_app1]
level=DEBUG
handlers=fileHandler
qualname=app1

[logger_app2]
level=DEBUG
handlers=fileHandler
qualname=app2

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=json
args=("logs/migration.log",)

[handler_fileHandler]
class=FileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=json
args=("logs/migration.log",'w')
```

In `main.py` I'm creating logging by using following code:

```
logging.config.fileConfig(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'logging.ini'),
                          disable_existing_loggers=False)
```

When I run `main.py` from the `project_name` folder I have to give path in `args` field `logging.ini` like below:

```
[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=json
args=("logs/migration.log",)

[handler_fileHandler]
class=FileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=json
args=("logs/migration.log",'w')
```

If I run `main.py` program from its path I have to give path like below:

```
[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=json
args=("../logs/migration.log",)

[handler_fileHandler]
class=FileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=json
args=("../logs/migration.log",'w')
```

It's difficult when I run program from different folder path because every time I have to change path. How can I handle this easily?

Comment: Your code and .ini file settings are making assumptions about the current working directory which is no longer true after it has been converted to an .exe. When running a script under the Python interpreter, a script can determine its own path by examining the built-in `__file__` variable just like you are doing when configuring logging. That trick commonly doesn't work after converting it to an exe. Look in the documentation of the exe converter you're using for "runtime information" — it will usually tell you how to do something equivalent in compiled scripts.

Comment: @martineau, I can make it work by changing the args path to ../../logs/migration.log",'w', But I want to do it dynamically, not ony for exe even though when I run python from other directory I have have to change path in logging.ini, I want something like over writing the logging.ini while ruuning something like that

Comment: Then your problem is solved, no?

Comment: @martineau, No it makes to difficult to change every time, because I had to take exe many times and I had test it my development environment many times, so I want some easy way to automate the path dynamically.

Comment: Then do as I suggested and stop using `__file__`. You should also indicate in your question what py-to-exe convertor you are using.

Comment: @martineau, I'm using pyinstaller, I guess __file__ is required otherwise I have to look to changes path to point logging.ini dynamically, I'll remove converting exe sentence in my question, because I said for scenario only.

Comment: As I said, there are usually equivalents to `__file__` that compiled scripts can use — and I am pretty sure pyinstaller has this in its documentation if you look for it. I just found it in 15 seconds, see [Run-time Information](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/runtime-information.html)